# PHP and contact form

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble getting the php script correct for my contact form. I managed to have it email me but it doesn't show a name, email or text in the email.

PHP Script

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = 'myemail@email.comm';
$subject = 'Hello';

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name);
echo "Your Message has been sent.";
?>
```

Contact Form

```
<form role="form" action="contact.php">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="InputName">Name</label>
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="InputEmail">Email Address</label>
<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="InputText">Message</label>
<input name="message" type="text" class="form-control" id="InputText" placeholder="Enter Text">
</div>

<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using POST variables, yet your form being the following:

```
<form role="form" action="contact.php">
```

doesn't have a POST method defined. Form defaults to GET when a method isn't defined.

Therefore, you will need to change your form to

```
<form role="form" action="contact.php" method="post">
```

---

From a comment you left:

*"I'm still having a problem where instead of giving me the email they input it gives an email created by the hosting company which is no good."*

**A:** It's most likely because of how you're using `From:` in your code, which is the person's name. Mail is expecting an Email address.

Replace:

```
mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name);
```

with:

```
mail ($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

and adding the following under `$subject = 'Hello';`

```
$header = "From: ". $name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
```

That way, you will see the person's name in the Email, while having a valid "From" header.

- Visit **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php** for more information on mail headers.

---

Additional notes:

I also suggest that you test if any of the fields aren't left empty using:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message']))
{
    // execute code
}
```

Otherwise, anyone could send an Email without any information at all.

You can also add an `else{}` to it like `else { echo "Please fill in all the fields."; }`

- This is a very basic method.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm still having a problem where instead of giving me the email they input it gives an email created by the hosting company which is no good.

Comment: @Robert I've made an edit to my answer to show you why and how. Reload it and near the bottom.

Comment: @Robert I've made an additional edit in regards to possible empty fields. You will find it near the bottom under "Additional notes".

Comment: @Fred-ii- you using `||`? The right would be `&&`?: `if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message']))`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento You have a point, thank you. I will make the change. Long day.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nice! Long day.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I think I should go watch TV now lol - *Cheers* and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your form needs the attribute

```
method="POST"
```

Without this, the browser defaults to `method="GET"`, which submits the form in the url, e.g., `http://example.com/default.php?name=First%20Last&email=...`

Answer (score 1):

You should specify POST method:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="contact.php">
```