# contact us form with email submision in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to design the contact us page in asp.net mvc. I would like to build a contact us form that also work as to send email to our email. This is the code in of front end; it is a design of form but I just copy this from a template. Can any body guide me to how to make it work or highlight any mistakes?

```
//code 
<div class="contact-form">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <form method="post" action="contact-post.html">
        <div>
            <span><label>Name</label></span>
            <span><input name="userName" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span><label>E-mail</label></span>
            <span><input name="userEmail" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span><label>Mobile</label></span>
            <span><input name="userPhone" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span><label>Subject</label></span>
            <span><textarea name="userMsg"> </textarea></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span><input type="submit" class="" value="Submit us"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP and contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219531/php-and-contact-form)

Comment: Please have a look at the answer already provided on another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23503008/4056108)